# Array out of bounds exception, Josephus

Tags: java, arrays, queue, bounds, josephus

I can't seem to figure out why I keep getting this error! It's my first time dealing with Queues. I'm sure the solution is simple and I'm probably missing something basic. Any guidance/help is greatly appreciated:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;


public class Josephus{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]),
            m = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        q.remove(new Integer(i));

    int k = 0;
    while (!q.isEmpty())
    {
        int x = q.remove();

        if (++k % m == 0)
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        else
            q.remove(x);

    System.out.println(x + " ");
    }
    }
}
```

The original prompt for this code is as follows:
Josephus problem. In the Josephus problem from antiquity, N people are in dire straits and agree to the following strategy to reduce the population. They arrange them- selves in a circle (at positions numbered from 0 to N–1) and proceed around the circle, eliminating every Mth person until only one person is left. Legend has it that Josephus figured out where to sit to avoid being eliminated. Write a Queue client Josephus that takes N and M from the command line and prints out the order in which people are eliminated (and thus would show Josephus where to sit in the circle).

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) q.remove(new Integer(i));` ... you remove something from a new queue? How should that work? You should try `q.add(...)` instead. And what should the line `q.remove(x);` do? The method `remove` doesn't accept any argument.

Comment: Do you pass parameters to your main method when you call it ? The only statements able to throw this exception are the declarations of n and m, using the args array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your program the wrong way... if you use command line, you must provide parameters :

```
java Josephus 5 6
```

Otherwise if you use Eclipse (for example), you must go to Run as, Run configurations, and add some arguments in the Program arguments field. You can also replace your first line by manually typed values :

```
int n = 10, m = 5;
```

I ran it with random sets of (m,n) values and it ran without any error (however, it didn't print anything).

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    q.remove(new Integer(i));
```

Why are you removing items from a newly created (empty) queue? Try adding them instead!

```
q.add(new Integer(i));
```

Comment: i tried adding them, instead of removing them from the queue. Everything compiles but when I run, i still get the out of bounds exception

Comment: You have an **Array**OutOfBoundException. A Queue is not an array, I think the issue comes from your way to call th program since the only array you use is args. Which line raises the exception ?

Comment: @Smn21 You should rethink the line `q.remove(x);`. You already removed the element `x` from the queue. If you want to remove similar elements, then this won't work either because `remove(Object o)` only removes one element. If you have to of them in you list, then one of them will remain in the queue.

Comment: @Dici 'int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]),'

Comment: So I was right, you don't pass any parameter to your program. It is never going to work like this :) Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Smn21 That's why you should always mark the line there the error occurs. This information changes a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Java thinks you're trying to call `remove(int index)` in the else statement of the if statement under the while loop, because you're passing in an int. As a work around, do what you did exactly in the for loop.

```
q.remove(new Integer(x));
```

Also, you need to make sure the user inputted the correct arguments in the command line.

```
if (args.length != 2){
    System.out.println("Invalid arguments.");
    return;
}

int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]),
    m = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

Comment: `remove(int index)`? There is no such method ... at least I can't find it. `Queue` supports `remove()` and the implemented Interface `Collection` supports `remove(Object o)`.

Comment: still getting the same out of bounds error, i've duplicated what i did in the for loop

Comment: The class java.util.linkedlist supports `remove(int index)`. [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: `LinkedList` may supports that, but the type of `q` is `Queue` and this type does not. So he can't access that method. He should declare `q` as (Linked)List to do that.

Answer (score 0):

An array out of bounds exception will occur when you try to access an element of an array that doesn't exist.

Check

args.length >= 2 before attempting to access the first 2 elements of this array.